# Why is there a floating "2" in my UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the image below you can see a *2* appearing to the right of my `UITableViewCell`'s accessory buttons.  This only appears when I am using section headers (which is what I'm currently adding to my existing `UITableView`.  If I fetch the data with `sectionNameKeyPath:nil` then the *2* doesn't appear.

My guess is that this *2* is appearing instead of the scrollIndicator.  The *2* always remains in the center of the `UITableView`.  When I don't use sections I see the scrollIndicator as expected.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Floating 2]

**Edit:**
This shows that the *floating 2* is a part of the scroll indicator.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the problem.  My superclass had the following code:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}
```

I must have picked up that code from an example somewhere when I setup my superclass for UITableViewController.  In this case I don't want index titles, just the scroll indicator, so I removed that method.

Comment: Good thing you found it :3

Answer (score 2):

hahah, that's great :) Butt! i think a way to find out where it's coming from is using the **Debug View Hierarchy**. Run your app and once you see the two in your table view:

[image: example]

once xcode has loaded the view from the Simulator, look for the two and click on it. at the top you'll see where this object is located.

Then i would try to back track on how it was added to this view. maybe it's part of a cell? etc.

I hope this helped getting closer to the answer :)

Comment: Good idea.  That confirmed that it is in fact a part of the scrollIndicator.

Comment: neat :D i'm glad :) i'm still cracking up how a magical two is just hiding in super small font, loved the screenshot :)